# Local homeomorphism is homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity

I am trying to prove that there is no continuous bijection $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R^3}$. 
 If there was, then for every real number $x$, $f|_{[x,x+1]}: [x,x+1] \to f([x,x+1])$ is a continuous bijection from a compact space to a hausdorff space, and therefore homeomorphism. Thus $f|_{(x,x+1)}$ is also homeomorphism on it's image. Does that imply that $f$ is homeomorphism? I know that $\mathbb{R} = \cup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} (x,x+1)$. So if $U \subset \mathbb{R}$ is open, we want to show that $f(U)$ is open in $\mathbb{R^3}$. we have: $f(U) = \cup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}f(U \cap (x,x+1))$. Now, we want to say that for all $x$, we have $f(U \cap (x,x+1))$ is open since $f|_{(x,x+1)}$ is homeomorphism, however, all we really know is that it is open in $f(x,x+1)$ and maybe not in $\mathbb{R^3}$. How can we fix that?

Comment: No, it doesn’t imply $f$ is a homeomorphism. The issue is that $f$ isn’t open, that is – the images of $f_|{(x,x+1)}$ aren’t open – their reunion is.

Comment: Please do not delete posts after receiving an answer.  This is disrespectful to the user who provided that answer and to the future readers who might benefit from this question and answer pair.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f\big(\cup_{n\in \Bbb N}[-n,n]\big)=\cup_{n\in \Bbb N}f[-n,n]=\Bbb R^3$. Since $\Bbb R^3$ is complete, one of the closed sets $f[-n,n]$ has non empty interior by Baire Category theorem, say $U:=\text{int}\ f[-m,m]\not=\emptyset$. Then, $f$ restricted to $[-m,m]$ onto $f[-m,m]$ is a homeomorphism as you said. Now, take a connected open ball $B$ contained in $U$, and since $f^{-1}$ is continuous we have $f^{-1}(B)$ is an open connected in $[-m,m]$. Note that connected subsets of $\Bbb R$ are intervals. So, removing one point from an interval is disconnected, but removing one point from an open subset of $\Bbb R^3$ is connected.